# The script is not able to get the html code of the external site. Curl PHP

Tags: php, curl

Help me figure out what is the reason that the script is not able to parse the html code of an external site. Work on the Curl script is in the remote access of the Hosting.
There is no access to the php.ini file.

Php version - 5.2.12

Curl version - libcurl / 7.21.0 GnuTLS / 2.8.6 zlib / 1.2.3.4 libidn / 1.15

OpenSSL - OpenSSL 1.0.2p 14 Aug 2018

Here is an example script itself, which results in a blank screen. For most sites, this script parses both http: // and https: // without problems. But there are a number of sites that do not lend themselves to this script, one of them is indicated in the script.

```
$urlrest = "https://instant-monitor.com/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($сh, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlrest);
$abc = curl_exec($ch);
echo 'curl_getinfo - '. curl_getinfo($ch) .'<br/><br/>';
echo 'curl_errno - '. curl_errno($ch) .'<br/><br/>';
echo 'curl_error - '. curl_errno($ch) .'<br/><br/>';
curl_close($ch);
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($abc);
var_dump($abc);
```

Comment: The site might check the user agent and block scripts.

Comment: A blank screen is usually a result of a 500 - Internal Error Message. Check your server error logs to find out why it failed.

Comment: There's a dodgy character in line 5 when I try to run this code, and I get a warning of an array to string conversion on line 13 after I fix it (by deleting where you posted `$ch` and re-typing it, so maybe a SO thing), but that's just your getinfo display line. Otherwise, it grabs a "string(2083206) " into `$abc`.

Comment: How did you do that? Can you tell us in detail? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no one who can cope with this task?